# Issue in using firebase.auth() in client side

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've a project in which a user needs to be signed in by using their email and password credentials.The user must submit his unique id(Roll number) along with email and password at the time of his account creation.

While doing the project, I've used `firebase-auth` on the login page to use `firease.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` function.But the issue here is anyone can create their accounts by simply running `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function in the console without submitting unique id(Roll number).

Now how can I restrict the users from such actions and making them to submit their **unique IDs** for their account creation

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want users to have to submit their unique ids when creating an account. If you do require this, then you'll need to add a validator that pings a collection with stored IDs to make sure that the unique Id they are submitting is in fact unique.

Instead, let Firebase create a unique ID for the user and allow them to register by email password.

Once a user registers with the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method, if successful it returns an object with auth credentials. in that returned object is a `user` property that includes a `uid` key:value

Comment: Consider users as students and they have their own IDs.I'm not bothering about uniqueness of IDs.I want to restrict the users from using ```firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()``` function in the console.If they tried they should not be prompted to create their accounts

Comment: You can't prevent them from trying to execute the call from the console. But, you can require the auth payload to include any data you wish, so if they attempt a request with an incorrect payload you can throw an error. Post the relevant code and I may be able to get more specific